# Applying entities in included XSLT documents causes error

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, dtd, libxslt

I have an XSL stylesheet with entity definition in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet SYSTEM "entities.dtd">
```

entities.dtd contains only one definition:

```
<!ENTITY copy "&#169;">
```

If I use &copy; in the document having the DOCTYPE declaration, everything works fine. But when I include another XSL document and try use the entity there, XSLT-processor says that 'copy' entity is not defined.

**How can I define a global DTD to use it in any included XSL stylesheet?**

Comment: Re: [How can I define a global DTD to use it in any included XSL stylesheet?] You can't. Every xslt stylesheet is a separate XML document and any XML document that doesn't have a DTD defining used entities is malformed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each module in your stylesheet is a freestanding XML document, and is submitted to the XML parser independently of other modules. It must therefore be well-formed it its own right, which means that it must define in its DTD any entities that it uses.